# Incorrect syntax in T-SQL statement in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have the following code:

```
USE [DB] INSERT INTO Extract2_EventLog VALUES (" + li.userId + ", '" + li.startTime.ToString() + "', '" + li.endTime.ToString() + "', '" + li.elapsedTime.ToString() + (li.actionType == ActionType.REPORT ? "', 'report')" : "', 'extract')', '" + status + "'");
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> {"Incorrect syntax near ', '.\r\nUnclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ''."}

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.. Anyone?

Comment: Look at the resulting string in the debugger, but it appears you don't have a closing quote after `li.elapsedTime.ToString()` (unless you are conditionally appending the string `'report'` to it).  Or better yet, switch to using parameters instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: are you trying to write an insert statement within C#? If so maybe it will be helpful to see what your insert statement should look like in tsql and then try to build it in C#.

Comment: The first thing to do is stop building SQL like that... right now. Use parameterized SQL and you may well find the problem just goes away... and you'll be preventing SQL Injection Attacks at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man....Where to start with this...

First off, you should be using stored procedures that accept parameters (variables from your application code).  Second, you should have a dataaccess layer in your application separating database calls and your user interface.  I can't possible stress enough how important this is and how bad your current approach is.  You will forever be fighting problems like this until you correct it.

But to address the question as it was asked...Your error is because your query string is malformatted.  Use the debugging tools to view the string before it is sent to the database and then you should be able to quickly determine what is wrong with it.  To troubleshoot, you can always cut and paste that string into SSMS, refine it there, and then make the necessary changes to your c# code.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement "you should be using stored procedures that accept variables", that is unnecessary and only adds complexity for the given example. Instead the OP should be using parametrized queries.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  First off, stored procedures are easier to make, modify, test, and troubleshoot than parameterized queries from an application.  Secondly, stored procedures can be used by different applications, so future changes will only need to be done in one spot.  If the queries are coming from the app, you'll be modifying the same code repeatedly.  Thirdly, there are security benefits, including SQL injection prevention (without having to scrub variables).  There are lots of reasons to use stored procedures.  There aren't any reasons to use parameterized queries

Comment: The SQL injection prevention given by stored procedure is **exactly the same** as with parameterized queries, because on the driver level they are handled the same. I'm not sure what you mean "scrub variables", because execution in both cases is identical. I know that stored procedures can have benefits, but for a question like this, in my opinion, a simpler example is better.

Comment: You are correct (whoops!).  However, from an application design, code maintenance, or logical organization perspective, I still strongly disagree with your assertion that SQL queries should be built by the application.  Furthermore, I strongly disagree that it adds complexity.  I'm a software developer and a DBA and I don't think I've ever seen a legitimate DESIGN reason to put database code inside an application.  Only time I've seen it happen is due to lack of skills, lack of access, or lack of time.

Comment: @StanShaw: Thanks for the input :)

Comment: No problem, Bryan.  Good luck with your dataacess layer - it won't be difficult and once you have it implemented, all of your applications can easily communicate with the database with MINIMAL code - and no hard to troubleshoot querystring building application code.  Also, you can think of a stored procedure like a global variable in an application.  You can modify it at any time and the changes will propagate through to everything that calls it, in real time, without having to redeploy any code.  Conversely, apps that build queries need to be separately modified and deployed with each change.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all look at the answer of Stan Shaw, next take a look at the comment of Jon Skeet!**

> The first thing to do is stop building SQL like that... right now. Use parameterized SQL and you may well find the problem just goes away... and you'll be preventing SQL Injection Attacks at the same time.

They sayed everything that's important and just for the sake of giving you a direct answer:

You have a `status + "'");` at your code which needs to be changed to `status + "')";` ...

...like this one:

```
string statement = "USE [DB] INSERT INTO Extract2_EventLog VALUES (" + li.userId + ", '" + li.startTime.ToString() + "', '" + li.endTime.ToString() + "', '" + li.elapsedTime.ToString() + (li.actionType == ActionType.REPORT ? "', 'report')" : "', 'extract')', '" + status + "')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of concatenating values into your query you should use a parameterized query or a stored procedure.

A rewrite of your code could be something like (depending on datatypes, etc):

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO Extract2_EventLog (userId, startTime, endTime, elapsedTime, actionType, [status]) VALUES (@userId, @startTime, @endTime, @elapsedTime, @actionType, @status)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", li.userId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", li.startTime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", li.endTime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@elapsedTime", li.elapsedTime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actionType", li.actionType == ActionType.REPORT ? "report" : "extract");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);

    connection.Open();
    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
}
```

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but this is bad advice.  You should have a data-access layer and you should use stored procedures.  Otherwise, you're going to have this spaghetti code repeated all over your application.  Granted, writing code like this with inline database calls is probably 5 minutes faster, but will cost you exponentially more in the future should you ever need to modify it - or make a similar call from elsewhere within the same application or from another application.

Comment: @StanShaw I agree that you need a data access layer or other abstraction, but for questions like this I'm keeping it simple. As discussed yesterday, I don't agree with your assertion that stored procedures are a must. I've seen enough atrocities, and performance problems caused by dogmatic use of stored procedures.

Comment: So your argument has changed from "it's simpler" to "it's faster"?!?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230668/stored-procedures-vs-parameterized-queries

Comment: @StanShaw We need to separate things: for answering these types of questions, I prefer simpler answers; introducing stored procedures and/or DAO/DAL in my opinion adds unnecessary complexity where the lessons should be *"don't concatenate values, use parameters"*. So I haven't changed my argument; in addition I am saying that I have seen enough ways of screwing up with stored procedures (both in (unnecessary) complexity/unreadability, and in performance) that I think that *"always use stored procedures"* is not the way. That said, stored procedures often are the right way, just not always.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot the "  at the beginning. So your code reverts sql with non sql.
AND your example seems to be incomplete.